# Call a jquery function after SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, modal-dialog

i try to call a function using jQuery after a SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog is loaded. Or to be more specific, i want to call the function while SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog is loaded.

This is the Dialog i want to Open:

```
var test = '<div id="correspondence"><div>Assign to:</div> <input class="inputPeoplePicker" type="text" name="taskname" id="txtTaskName"></div>';

$('body').append(test);

jQuery(".inputPeoplePicker").peoplePicker();

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    html: document.getElementById('correspondence'),
    title: "Aufgabe erstellen",
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    autoSize: true,
});
```

This is the jQuery command to load the function:

```
jQuery(".inputPeoplePicker").peoplePicker();
```

The peoplePicker() function is a function i call from jQuery Plugin i got from here: [Plugin](http://customsp.blogspot.de/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-jquery-peoplepicker.html)

The People Picker works well on a InputBox outside of the ModalDialog.

My Problem is that the PeoplePicker suggestions are shown behind the ModalDialog. It looks like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66qX7.png)

I believe that, when i call the function inside the ModalDialog the PeoplePicker suggestions are shown correctly.

Thank you.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My automatic guess is that the z-index of the SP.UI.ModalDialog is higher than that of peoplePicker.

Try tweaking the token-input.css file and setting the z-index higher, use your browser's element inspector to see the values.

Comment: That was really, quick. Thank your very much!